Coq: unfold a class nested in the goal
I'm a beginner in Coq.
I got the following class:
Class TotalPreorder (R : relation A) : Prop := {
  TotalPreOrder_Reflexive :: Reflexive R (*| 2*) ;
  TotalPreOrder_Transitive :: Transitive R (*| 2*);
  TotalPreOrder_StrongConnected :: StrongConnected R (*| 2*)
}.

How to "unfold" this class when my proof comes to this:
Goal 1

R : relation A
StrictWeakOrdering_Irreflexive0 : Irreflexive R
StrictWeakOrdering_Transitive0 : Transitive R
StrictWeakOrdering_TransitiveIncomparability0 : TransitiveIncomparability R
(1 / 1)
TotalPreorder (fun x y : A => R x y -> False)

There, I don't know how to make any progress.

You should be able to use split here, because a Class (or a Record or Structure) is an inductive type with exactly one constructor.
In any case, if you do Print TotalPreorder, you will see that Coq produces a name for the constructor of your class, Build_TotalPreorder in this case. So you should also be able to use apply Build_TotalPreorder.
